# C# Changing class method at run-time

Tags: c#, .net, runtime

I need to extend the behavior of an instance, but I don't have access to the original source code of that instance. For example:

```
/* I don't have the source code for this class, only the runtime instance */
Class AB
{
  public void execute();
}
```

in my code I would to intercept every call to execute, compute some sutff and then call the original execute, something like

```
/* This is how I would like to modify the method invokation */
SomeType m_OrgExecute;

{
    AB a = new AB();
    m_OrgExecute = GetByReflection( a.execute );
    a.execute = MyExecute;
}

void MyExecute()
{
    System.Console.Writeln( "In MyExecute" );
    m_OrgExecute();
}
```

Is that possible?

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you want the [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

```
class AB
{
   public void execute() {...}
}

class FlaviosABDecorator : AB
{
   AB decoratoredAB;

   public FlaviosABDecorator (AB decorated)
   {
       this.decoratedAB = decorated;
   }

   public void execute()
   {
       FlaviosExecute();  //execute your code first...
       decoratedAB.execute();
   }

   void FlaviosExecute() {...}
}
```

You'd then have to modify the code where the `AB` object is used.

```
//original code
//AB someAB = new AB();

//new code
AB originalAB = new AB();
AB someAB = new FlaviosABDecorotor(originalAB);

/* now the following code "just works" but adds your method call */
```

Comment: This has a severe downside: all third-party code that is programmed to use `AB` will keep using the original class.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this directly via reflection, etc.

In order to have your own code injected like this, you'll need to create a modified version of their assembly, and use some form of [code injection](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DotnetInternals_Injection.aspx).  You cannot just "change a method" of an arbitrary assembly at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at PostSharp.  It can "rewire" existing compiled assemblies to add the kind of before and after processing that you are looking for.  I'm not 100% sure it will address your need but it very well might.

http://www.sharpcrafters.com/aop.net

Comment: This requires the assembly to be attributed, since that's how post sharp determines what to rewrite.

Comment: @Reed: You can use [assembly:] level attributes with PostSharp. That said, those probably have to go in the AssemblyInfo.cs of the assembly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dynamic proxy such as [Castle Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Because I favor composition over inheritance (and because inheritance might not be an option if the class is sealed), I would wrap `AB` in my own class called `FlaviosAB` like so...

```
public class FlaviosAB
{
    private AB _passThrough;
    public FlaviosAB(){
        _passThrough = new AB();
    }

    public void execute()
    {
        //Your code...
        Console.WriteLine("In My Execute");
        //Then call the passThrough's execute.
        _passThrough.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: This gets past any problem of the original class being sealed. Depending on how many other public methods on AB the caller needs, more might need to be expressed through the wrapper.

Comment: @jdk:  More might be necessary, but it wasn't specified in the question so I didn't include it :) Also, your gravatar looks just like my tattoo :)

Comment: If your tattoo image was published on the Internet then I stole it as my Gravatar. I can only give +1 to your answer once, otherwise I'd provide a second for the cool tattoo! :)

Answer (score 0):

if AB is not sealed, then you can inherit the class and override the method. in this case with new

```
class ABChild : AB {
    public new void execute() {
        System.Console.Writeln( "In MyExecute" );
    }
}
```

According to the comments, you should invocate this *new* method, within an ABChild class:

```
void Invoke() {
    ABChild a = new ABChild();
    a.execute();
}
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: This will not work if the caller of execute() is using an AB.  It will call the original method on AB unless you cast it to ABChild.

Answer (score 0):

You could always inherit from the class and override the execute() method (if the class isn't sealed, and the method isn't private at least.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wrapper class:

```
Class ABWrapper
{
  private AB m_AB;

  ABWrapper( AB ab )
  {
    m_AB = new AB();
  }

  public void execute()
  {
    // Do your stuff, then call original method
    m_AB.execute();
  }
}
```

This is a good approach when `AB` implements an *interface* (you did not mention that, though). In this case `ABWrapper` should implement the same interface. When you use a *factory* or even *dependency injection* to create your `AB` instances you can replace them there easily with your wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a dynamic proxy. Find more information [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dynamicproxy.aspx)

Basically you are extending the base class and overriding some methods with yours. Now you need to re-assign the object being called by an instance of yours and all the calls will pass through your object first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of the Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP) solutions from this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833729/built-in-aop-in-c-is-it-on-the-way) will come in handy...