# Hook a method's call of another .net process

Tags: .net, hook, easyhook

I have .net app. It has some methods that i'd like to monitor (hook)

Using Easyhook i can inject into running this process.
But how can i find method's address for hooking?

Comment: Isn't easyhook intended only to hook into unmanaged calls? For hooking into managed calls see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169552/is-there-a-way-to-hook-a-managed-function-in-c-sharp-like-i-would-a-unmanaged-fu).

Comment: hum, good point, thx