# Change Microsoft SourceCode Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#, console-application

I am working with some legacy code that `Console.Write` and `Console.WriteLine` are used a lot. I would like to fire an event every time this method is called.

That said, I went to the [OpenSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs) library and found out that there isnt an event that is fired when this is called. So my question is:

Is there a way to change the code that this applicaion is using to fire an event every time this is called?

Or, if not, is there a way to do this without changing the code?

Comment: As alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169552/is-there-a-way-to-hook-a-managed-function-in-c-sharp-like-i-would-a-unmanaged-fu#6171718 ;-)